# Why is there error on System.out.print(rev);?

Tags: java, loops

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String rev = "";
    String input = "Hello World";
    int length = input.length();
    for (int i = length - 1; 1 >= 0; i--){

    rev = rev + input.charAt(i);    

}
System.out.print(rev);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've copy and pasted that block and code, the error is because `System.out.print(rev);` has been placed outside the `main()` function block.

Comment: Move the ```System.ou....``` statement inside of the ```main()``` function block. (Before the closing ```}```)

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  String rev = "";
  System.out.println("Enter a string to reverse: ");
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  String input = keyboard.nextLine();
  
  int length = input.length();
  
  for (int i = length - 1; 1 >= 0; i--)
   
  rev = rev + input.charAt(i);
  
  System.out.print(rev);
  
    } 
} it still display error if I do this.

Comment: Remove one of the ```}```'s on the end of your method.

Comment: If a solution has helped you, please tick it as a useful answer, and mark it as useful!

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "Welcome Java";
char[] strArray = str.toCharArray();

for (int i = strArray.length-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
    System.out.print(strArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding some explanation to your code. Thank you!